# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hdbcli'

Tags: python, hana

I am trying to run the code where I am getting the error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hdbcli'
I tried using !pip install hdbcli
but getting the below error now

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement hdbcli (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for hdbcli
```

then I also used

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
pip install opencv-python
!pip install hdbcli
```

Still the error remains

Comment: are you sure that you are using latest version of pip and the module?

Comment: pip3 install hdbcli

Comment: I have installed the latest version of pip too still the error exists                            
 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement hdbcli (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for hdbcli